# Odoo open new window

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I want to create a button in opportunities of CRM in Odoo 11. I want to open a window with all messages of this opportunity (Model mail.message)

I tried to create my first addon.

Here is my structure:

- /odoo/addons/test

  - __init__.py
  - __manifest__.py
  - models

    - __init__.py
    - test.py

Here is my code:

/odoo/addons/test/__manifest__.py

```
{
'name': 'test',
'version': '2.0',
'category': 'Sales',
'sequence': 5,
'summary': 'test',
'description': "",
'website': 'https://test.net',
'depends': [
    'crm'
],
'data': [
],
'demo': [
],
'css': [],
'installable': True,
'application': True,
'auto_install': False,
}
```

/odoo/addons/test/__init__.py

```
from . import models
```

/odoo/addons/test/models/__init__.py

```
from . import test
```

/odoo/addons/test/models/test.py

```
from odoo import models, fields


class test_test(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    @api.multi
    def test_test(self):
        return {
            'name': 'test_test',
            'res_model': 'mail.message',
            'view_type': 'list',
            'view_mode': 'tree,list',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'inline'
        }
```

crm.lead.form.opportunity

```
 <button name='%(test_test)d' string="test" type="action" />
```

I installed my application but the button does not work and it does not show any error. And I am not able to see my action in the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to call a function from the view you need to define object type button like below.

```
<button name='test_test' string="test" type="object" />
```

it will call function `test_test` in your model `crm.lead`, (make sure your button is in the `crm.lead` model view.)

and you need to change your function like below

```
@api.multi
def test_test(self):
    return {
        'name': 'test_test',
        'res_model': 'mail.message',
        'view_type': 'list',
        'view_mode': 'tree,list',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new' # will open a popup with mail.message list
    }
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to do it in another model, in my custom module. How I can do that?.

Comment: Hi. Finally I solved it, with my code and your button. I had mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: I just miss the domain to view only the messages of the opportunity and de delete button of messages. I tried adding view_id to the return with out success and the domain broke the code. I tried "[('res_id','=', self.id)]"  to the domain and "mail.message.search" to the view_id. Any help can be appreciated.